# How many times can a user change their profile name?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, display-names

Is there a limit to the users to change his/her profile display name? If there is how many is that, until the user gets locked to the last name?

Comment: Current rules at Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180/293308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180) by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) standard rules are;

- Only one display name change is allowed every 30 days
- User accounts less than 2 days old may change their displayname at will
- There is a 15 minute grace period after each change during which you may change your display name at will